# Accessing parallel arrays in Django templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My view code looks basically like this:

```
context = Context() 
context['some_values'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
context['other_values'] = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
```

I would like my template code to look like this:

```
{% for some in some_values %} 
  {% with index as forloop.counter0 %} 
    {{ some }} : {{ other_values.index }} <br/> 
  {% endwith %} 
{% endfor %}
```

And I would expect this to output:

```
a : 4 <br/> 
b : 8 <br/> 
c : 15 <br/> 
d : 16 <br/> 
e : 23 <br/> 
f : 42 <br/>
```

Is this possible?  I'm finding that my "with" statement is actually working, but then using that variable as a reference isn't working.  I suspect that for {{ other_values.index }} it's doing other_values['index'] instead of other_values[index].  Is this possible?

Comment: I could always write a custom template tag for this use case, but it seems like overkill.  I'd hate to have to say {{ other_values|access:index }}.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`zip(some_values, other_values)`, then use it in template

```
from itertools import izip
some_values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
other_values = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
context['zipped_values'] = izip(some_values, other_values)

{% for some, other in zipped_values %}
    {{ some }}: {{ other }}  <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'd use `itertools.izip` instead.

Comment: I'd rather not have to add more to the context, and this makes the context data quite redundant.  Additionally, if I change my template (say, to not access these parallel arrays anymore) then I have to remember to clean up the view code.  It feels like it straddles the line between data & presentation.

Comment: @slacy: Your question is not purely about presentation. The association between items is essential in two "parallel" arrays.  "Parallel" arrays are really just 2-tuples waiting to be created.  You *should* put them together in the view function because they absolutely belong together logically.  That's why you're presenting them together.

Comment: @PiotrLegnica: absolutely. Fixed. Also with izip it wont create a huge new structure in memory.